# How to Write an applet where the screen keeps track of the highest number entered by the user so far

Tags: java

It's a bit confusing i know, how to add text/numbers to the TextField, but o dont know how to Write an applet where the The screen keeps track of the highest number entered by the user so far.

```
public class Test extends Applet {

TextField t1;
String tekst, tekst1;
int num1, num2,num3;


public void init() {
    t1 = new TextField("", 30);
    t1.addActionListener(new TextListener());
    add(t1);
    tekst = "";



}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setSize(400, 400);
    t1.setBounds(20, 60, 80, 20);

    g.drawString("Highest number: " + num1, 20, 50);


}

class TextListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();
        tekst = t1.getText();
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(tekst);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think the first advice is "Don't write an Applet". That's technology from the early `90s that isn't supported by modern day browsers. I'd suggest you write a Swing or JavaFX application.

Comment: You don't need to override the paint method. Just add a JLabel to show the highest value and set the text of the JLabel in the TextListener. Also remove the call to repaint() in actionPerformed.

Comment: @keuleJ Note that this is an `Applet`, not a `JApplet`. This uses AWT, not Swing. I guess your advice can be changed to using `Label`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ah yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

in terms of the algorithm to check which number is higher, initialize num1 as 0 or the lowest accepted number then:

```
try{
   num2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
   if(num2 > num1)
   num1 = num2;
   //print num1 to wherever you want the largest value to show
   reprint();
}
catch(RuntimeException e)
{
   //tell the user to input a valid number;
}
```

A few things to note:

1. Be careful what constitutes the user "inputting a number" as updating on input may have the applet processing unfinished inputs(ie "8" instead of "80").
2. As mentioned by others showing the output to a dedicated part of the screen such as a JLabel would be clearer and simpler than managing both on the input field.
3. As shown, be careful of non-integer input as the text field accepts any characters, not just numbers.